# What's so special about the Fishcake?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-heavy

Recently I had bought SpaceChem and upon completing all the research challenges, I was able to craft 2 items in TF2 and one of them was the [Fishcake](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Fishcake). The stats of the Fishcake are identical to the [Dalokohs Bar](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Dalokohs_Bar), so is there a difference in what this 2 items can do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no difference, it just looks differently.

There are many "copies" of weapons with different name and look, for example, [HHHH](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Horseless_Headless_Horsemann%27s_Headtaker) and [Nessie's Nine Iron](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Nessie%27s_Nine_Iron) act exactly the same as [Eyelander](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Eyelander).

Answer (score 5):

No, the Fishcake is simply a reskinned version of the Dalokohs Bar. Both items have the same stats and behave the same way, the only difference is visual. TF2 has quite a few such items, [the official wiki has a list](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Category:Reskins).